# how to remove common elements between two cell arrays from the first one in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How to remove common elements between two cell arrays from the first one in MATLAB?
for example:

```
 A={[1 3 2],[2 3 1],[3 1 2]} & B={[1 3 2],[3 2 1]}
```

A & B are two cell arrays. I want to find A-B. for this purpose I want to remove common elements between A & B from A. How can I do that?

Comment: Will any of these elements in your cell arrays ever be floating-point numbers?  If they are, then there's a potential danger in that elements may remain as exact equality is not guaranteed due to floating-point precision.

Comment: You could use [setdiff(A,B)](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) in case the arrays contained single elements (numbers/strings).

Comment: the elements of cell array is randperm of an integer number.

Comment: To clarify, are you looking to compare the sets of vectors or the numbers within the vectors? If its the numbers themselves, A would become empty correct?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small function that works when `A` and `B` both are vectors:

```
function A = celldiff(A, B)
for ii = 1:length(B)
    inA = arrayfun(@(x) isequal(A{x}, B{ii}), 1:length(A));
    A = A(~inA);
end
end
```

Example with your defined inputs:

```
>> A={[1 3 2],[2 3 1],[3 1 2]};
>> B={[1 3 2],[3 2 1]};
>> C = celldiff(A, B);
>> C{:}
ans =
     2     3     1
ans =
     3     1     2
```